# Smooth out requests to rate limitted API

Tags: algorithms, rate-limiting

```
        wasted requests     not enough time for those requests
                 |                       |
                 |                       |
(1) |-x--x-----------------x----x--x--x| x  x   (executing requests)
      ..                   .    .....           (sending requests)
(2) |-x--x-----------------x----xxxx-x-|        (executing requests)

(3) |xx-x--x--x---x---x----x----x-----x|        (executing requests, ideal)
```

I'm trying to figure out when to send requests to an API that would be spaced as much consistently as possible.

The most straght-forward solution would be to keep the requests spaced enough so that the API wouldn't throttle (1). However this technique wastes a lot of requests.

I came up with the idea to let the requests run a lot more quickly when there's a lot of space left and slow down when at the end (3). However when the API after the interval received its 120th request in the last minute, the requests were too slow. It'd be optimal to send the every 0.5 seconds (60/120), but my script was sending them every 0.85 seconds.

How would I accomplish something similar to the example show in (2)?

Edit:
Here's the code I tried. It's a lot finnicky.

```py
class Limitter:
    def __init__(self, num, interval, minimal=.2):
        self.num = num
        self.interval = interval
        self.minimal = minimal

        self._next = None

        self._requests = []
        self._lock = Lock()

    def _get_duration(self):
        now = time.time()
        self._requests = filter(lambda x: now - x < self.interval, self._requests)

        if len(self._requests) < 2:     # if not enough requests stored, return interval / num
            return float(self.interval) / self.num
        else:
            oldest = self._requests[0]
            newest = self._requests[-1]
            req_left = self.num - len(self._requests)

            if self.num == len(self._requests):             # if num reached, do this. It doesn't work at all
                return max(.5, oldest - (now - 60) + .4)    # tried to hotfix with some constants

            time_left = float(oldest + self.interval - newest)
            unit_time = time_left / req_left
            slant = -1.4 / self.num * req_left + 1.7        # slant that enables the different timing (first short, then long)(just a linear function)
            return unit_time * slant

    def acquire(self):
        with self._lock:
            now = time.time()

            if self._next:
                duration = self._next - time.time()
                if duration > 0:
                    time.sleep(duration)

            delta = self._get_duration()
            self._requests.append(time.time())
            self._next = time.time() + delta

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = Limitter(120, 60)

    for i in range(240):
        l.acquire()
```

I'm developing an "API" for Hypixel API. They have a limit of 120 requests per minute. The requests are just communicating with the official API. I'm just trying to get information as fast as possible. I don't think the limit is there to protect the API from me.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416911/smooth-out-requests-to-rate-limitted-api "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: @gnat I'm sorry, but I got told to post here. What do you think I should've done instead? I'm really desperate for the solution.

Comment: That's alright. I think your question fits here better. Just delete the post on SO. But at the same time you should read your question again And consider imrpoving its quality. There Is a lot for  the reader to think what you really meant.

Comment: @slepic Oh sorry, didn't think about that.

Comment: can you explain how/why your script is not doing requests fast enough? Do you have actual code?

Comment: Please clarify a number of things: - where does the rate limit come from? - where do the requests come from? - do you collaborate with the API provider, or is your app the kind of potentially abusive client that the rate limit should protect against?

Comment: Do 1, but without the big gap in the middle?

Comment: @MartinK It's not fast enough, because at the end I'm trying to send the requests more slowly.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner editted my answer

Comment: @user253751 The thing is the program doesn't know when the requests will occur. It's a console application. The user issues those requests.

Comment: Usually 120 requests per minute means you get another request every 0.5 seconds, up to a maximum of 120. Are you sure they do it in 1 minute blocks?

Comment: @user253751 yes. I had multiple accidents when my program just burst a lot of requests at once and 120 went through. Others got throttled. After 1 minute all was fine. The reset time is not known and it's not something nice (hh:mm:00) so I can't work with that.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't analyze your solution completely, but it looks a bit too complicated in my opinion. I'd simply keep the last 120 request timestamps (as you do) and delay each request that would be less than 60 seconds after the 120th request before. Then you will be able to handle bursts but still ensure that there are never more than 120 requests within any 60-second interval. If the user manages to create 120 requests within 30 seconds, he/she will have to wait half a minute before the next one can be processed. If you set a minimum delay between requests you will reduce maximum burst frequency, but users with intermittent bursts and pauses will be at a slight disadvantage. In practice, this might not make a real difference, though.

Comment: I considered this as well, but I don't want the user to see a burst and then wait a while. On the other hand I don't want to specify a minimum delay, because it would limit the maximum amount of requests per the interval. I was just curious, whether there is a similar mathematical problem of making the requests delay smooth that has a solution. Seems like there isn't though.